# Labelling stacked bar chart with positive and negative values

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, bar-chart

I am using ggplot2 to create a stacked bar chart with negative values, and trying to add sum of the parts as label on top of each bar. The code works fine for bars without negative values, but the label when a negative value is present stays inside the bar.

Example:

```
test = c("Test1", "Test1", "Test1", "Test2", "Test2", "Test2", "Test3", "Test3", "Test3")  
student = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C")  
value = c(5,5,5,3,3,3,-2,6,7)

dummy = data.frame(test, student, value)

g = ggplot(data=dummy, aes(x=student, y=value, fill=test)) +   
      geom_bar(stat="identity") +   
      scale_fill_manual(values=c("brown4", "steelblue", "goldenrod3")) +
      geom_text(aes(label=value), size =3, position=position_stack(vjust=0.5), colour="white") +
      theme_classic() + 
      theme(text=element_text(family="serif", size=15, colour="black")) +   
      theme(axis.title=element_text(family="serif", size=15, colour="black")) +   
      theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +   
      theme(legend.position = c(0.2, 0.7)) +
      stat_summary(fun.y = sum, aes(label = ..y.., group = student), geom = "text", vjust = -1) +
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-4,20))

g
```

The result is the following chart:

[image: Chart with stacked bars and negative values]
The sum for the bars without negative value works fine on top of the bar, but the sum for the bar with the negative value (Student A) is in the middle of the red bar.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Sorry, first time posting here. Edited now.

Comment: Major props for providing a nice reproducible example on your very first question. Makes it very easy to help.

Answer (score 2):

You use `fun.y = sum` as the summary function, which adds all the `y` values in the group, including negative values. This gives the correct sum for the label, but a bad position. For the position calculation, we want to calculate a sum of only the values greater than 0.

`stat_summary` let's us specify up to 3 functions, `fun.y`, `fun.ymin`, and `fun.ymax`. We'll modify `fun.y`, the position, to be the sum of positive values, and we'll add in a `fun.ymax` as the regular `sum` and use that for the label:

```
g = ggplot(data=dummy, aes(x=student, y=value, fill=test)) +   
      geom_bar(stat="identity") +   
      scale_fill_manual(values=c("brown4", "steelblue", "goldenrod3")) +
      geom_text(aes(label=value), size =3, position=position_stack(vjust=0.5), colour="white") +
      theme_classic() + 
      theme(text=element_text(family="serif", size=15, colour="black")) +   
      theme(axis.title=element_text(family="serif", size=15, colour="black")) +   
      theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +   
      theme(legend.position = c(0.2, 0.7)) +
      stat_summary(fun.y = function(y) sum(y[y > 0]), fun.ymax = sum,
                   aes(label = ..ymax.., group = student), geom = "text", vjust = -1) +
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-4,20))
g
```

[image]

Comment: Clever use of `ymax`!! I like it.

Comment: Thanks Gregor. I already did that, it says that it was record, but it does not appear in the page because I have less than 15 reputation...weird, but many thanks again, easy to work solution!